# what is the best approach to the cost compare

Tags: reasoning

If one bottle costs more than one cap, which statement is true?

1. one bottle + one cap costs more than two bottles
2. one bottle costs more than two caps
3. two caps cost more than one bottle
4. one bottle + one cap costs more than two caps
5. two bottles cost more than three caps

how to solve questions like this? what should be the approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve it by rewriting the expressions into inequalities and graphing it out.

#### Making inequalities

For how to graph it, check [this link](https://saylordotorg.github.io/text_intermediate-algebra/s05-07-solving-inequalities-with-two-.html)

So I would basically see this as a set of inequalities, substituting caps with `x` and bottles with `y`

One bottle costs more than one cap, then becomes `y > x`

one bottle + one cap costs more than two bottles, becomes `y + x > y + y` and then rewrite this to `y < x`

one bottle costs more than two caps, becomes `y > 2*x`

and so on.

#### Plotting it out

Then plot the two inequalities into a coordinate system, like shown [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/x2f8bb11595b61c86:inequalities-systems-graphs/x2f8bb11595b61c86:graphing-two-variable-inequalities/v/graphing-linear-inequalities-in-two-variables-example-2)

For the first question you'll see that no values satifies both `y > x` and `y < x`